# Cannot copy files in Seagate portable Hard disks (Ownership problem)

Tags: partitioning, permissions, hard-drive, external-hdd

I have recently purchased a `Seagate Backup Plus portable` hard disk (2TB), I am mostly using it in Ubuntu system hence I formatted it with the following command

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb
```

where `/dev/sdb` is it's path and can be seen from this command

```
sudo parted -l
```

[image]

formatting went fine without errors but after that, I observed that I cannot be able to copy any file in it as I don't have permission. As can be seen from the below screenshot only root has permission

[image: .png]

```
lsblk -f
```

[image]

How can I allow the nonroot user to copy / paste / modify files in the portable hard disk

Comment: Run `sudo chown $USER: /path/to/mount/point`.

Comment: @RoVo I tried the above command still cannot be able to copy

Comment: Can we see `ls -l /media/$USER/<name_of_device>`, and add `lsblk -f`?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen issuing `ls -l` returns this https://i.postimg.cc/QNmdfmRR/er3.png

Comment: Please put that into your post and said `ls -l /media/$USER/<name_of_device>` not `ls -l`!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Hello, I have updated the question as per your suggestion

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Device Name: `8ba5c044-fd8c-406c-afb5-6063fc9258f6`, On issuing the following command `ls -l /media/$atinesh/8ba5c044-fd8c-406c-afb5-6063fc9258f6`, I am getting an error `ls: cannot access '/media//8ba5c044-fd8c-406c-afb5-6063fc9258f6': No such file or directory`

Comment: The command should be `ls -l /media/atinesh/8ba5c044-fd8c-406c-afb5-6063fc9258f6`!!!